# How to Record Screen, when app is in background?

Tags: ios, swift, screen-recording, replaykit

--> I've made screen recorder using RPSScreenRecord which is able to record screen in foreground. But how can I continue record screen when app is in background ?
--> Any Help and suggestion will be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You will need to create a broadcast extension

Comment: @Paulw11 can you please guide me to tutorial or some code snippet ? I added BroadcastUI and BroadcastUpload extensions in my project. But I don't know how to use them.

Comment: @Jecky Can u guide me on this?

Answer (score 3):

This is the simplest way to record screen in background.
Also no need to create Broadcast upload extension.
Simply create RPSystemBroadcastPickerView and start recording in background it will also work when app is in background or forced closed.

```
var broadCastPicker : RPSystemBroadcastPickerView?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    broadCastPicker = RPSystemBroadcastPickerView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
    self.view.addSubview(broadCastPicker!)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

RPSScreenRecord won't work, when application in background.